# How to install xamarin in Visual Studio 2013 ultimate

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2013

please some one let me know how can i install xamarin in visual studio 2013 ultimate. i don't want to uninstall  visual studio 2013 because i have its key.
is it good for me to work in VS-2013 instead of VS-2015 or later versions.

Comment: You should use visual studio 2017. Xamarin is now part of Visual studio, in the past it was a separate installation. I would stick with VS 2017. There is also a community edition for free if you do not use it commercially.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition is free and includes all the necessary Xamarin components.  Visual Studio 2013 will not support the current version of Xamarin.